# Can we have more possible migration targets?

Tags: feature-request, migration

Linguistics.SE tends to attract various language-specific grammar and usage questions, which are off-topic here—we even have a special close reason specifically for that case.

But many of these would be on-topic on other sites in the network. For the one I'm most active on, for example, [Latin.SE](https://latin.stackexchange.com) would accept several of the Greek and Latin questions that appear here. I've also seen quite a lot of questions about [English Language and Usage](https://elu.stackexchange.com), [Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com), and [German](https://german.stackexchange.com).

Would it be possible to add these as migration options to the close-vote dialogue? Right now the only migration option listed is to Linguistics.Meta, but we seem to get far more questions about English grammar than about site policies.

EDIT: And as of today, we are no longer in beta, and thus can have migration paths enabled!

Answer (score 5):

No, unfortunately. As long as Linguistics is in beta, Stackexchange will not enable such features. Ref.: 
[What are the limitations in Beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296832/what-are-the-limitations-in-beta)

---

Update: The site is no longer in beta, but [the old restrictions remain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331751/236093). I'll add migration targets when such facilities are made available here.

Comment: As of today, this site [is no longer in Beta](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1860/1009), so this answer may require amendment.

Comment: @bytebuster We'll have to wait for things to settle down. It still says "Custom Off-Topic Close Reasons 3 / 3 active" on the close reasons page.