# Announcing a "Graduation" election for 2021

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**:  Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **August 23**, as your “graduation” election as a result of having [lost your beta label a while back](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1860/congratulations-youre-no-longer-in-beta).

The timeline:

- On August 16, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on August 23, users can [nominate themselves](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/election/1). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a second Meta post, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- On August 30, if there are 4 or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than 4 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates who've nominated (and aren't already pro-tem mods) and we'll default to considering this a "pro-tem election" just to try to bring the total number of moderators on the site up to 3 (for full details of the process, [see the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections).There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on September 7, (or September 14, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: Is this election just for new mods, or do the existing mods have to nominate themselves too?

Comment: @curiousdannii current moderators also need to nominate themselves if they would continue as mods.