# Why can't we move language questions to their respective stack exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

Today I came across a particular question: [Parsing of the word "Language" in NLP](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/37556/parsing-of-the-word-language-in-nlp)

> I want to translate the word language in the term NLP to the Arabic language.

Having recently received my privilege to vote to close/move questions I wanted to be able to move this question to another site, *before remembering that there wasn't an Arabic Stack Exchange*. That being said, I noticed that we can't request to move any question about German, French etc. to their respective [German](https://german.stackexchange.com/) or [French](https://french.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchanges.

In fact, it seems we can only move from Linguistics Stack Exchange to the Meta:

[image]

And yet, there is an option there to **deny**, language specific questions.

[image]

Isn't this very counterproductive? I mean we should only have to use this option for language which aren't yet available. But otherwise we *should* be able to move the question to the 15 or so sites, it only makes sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we have more possible migration targets?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/can-we-have-more-possible-migration-targets)

Comment: i suppose it does ;/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might not be able to, but moderators can.

If you feel a question should be migrated to a particular site, you can flag it for moderator attention and report that to us. If it is in fact a fit for the other site, it will be migrated.

Please note however that if it's a fit here, and could be there too, it will stay here.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the principle of "Don't Migrate Trash". While we get a few good well-researched questions on language usage and grammar here, most aren't great. It's probably better in general to close them here but leave comments suggesting that they ask on other sites, and reminding them to read the help pages on those sites in order to understand what quality standards they expect.

Comment: While I will be sure to consider "not migrating trash", I still believe quite a few questions are worth salvaging

Comment: @madprogramer Definitely, and when a really good question comes along you can write a custom flag suggesting it be migrated as Alenanno said.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact rationale, but it is general to SE so there is probably some discussion on Meta SE that Meta experts know about. I *think* is has to do with the fact that moving a question from site to site is thought to require a special skill set which is different from the skill set needed for topic-specific technical evaluation. Basically, it calls for skills at moderation, and not everybody should be allowed to do it, just as not everybody should be given a diamond hammer. That is, you need to not just be able to say "This doesn't belong here", you have to be able to say "This belongs there", and to do that with great restrint. I am betting that it only takes a single moderator action to migrate a question (and a single moderator action to reject a migration).

I also suspect that the programming needed to create a public "vote to migrate" option would be non-trivial. We don't need to agree on exactly *why* a question should be closed, because that is just supplemental information on a single conclusion: "this question is closed". Migration requires a specific target, and the set of targets is open-ended – what if there are 2 votes to migrate to French, 2 to migrate to German, and 1 to migrate to Conlang? The answer is not self-evident, and significantly affects how such an option would be implemented.

Comment: But there are a lot of monolingual questions which are distinctly language-specific. I feel that this attitude ignores this sizable collection, where the voting route should be trivial.